# How do you write copyright in Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to add a copyright at the footer of my WordPress Website. I try custom CSS & HTML but it takes so much time. I want an easy & fastest method for doing this stuff!

Answer (score 0):

One easy and fast method for adding a copyright notice in the footer of your WordPress website is to use a plugin. There are many WordPress plugins that allow you to easily add a copyright notice in the footer of your site without writing any CSS or HTML code. Some popular plugins that you can use include "Easy Footer Scripts", "Footer Putter", and "WP Copyright Footer". Simply install one of these plugins and follow the instructions to add your copyright notice.